# Gradle Script to include Versioning in you file in Java

Tags: java, git, gradle, versioning

I need to write a gradle script to auto version my application on every commit in git in Java application.
Can someone help me how do we proceed with the gradle script.

Comment: Usually, the version is incremented after the build (and not whole, just it's build number if it's used) or after release and not on every git commit. Are you sure that you need it on every commit? If yes, you have to trigger gradle task on every commit in git and this way I don't know, what is the reason to do it with Gradle and not with some sh-scripts or something else.

Comment: I am looking for a gradle script so that upon each commit in git the version of the commit gets reflected in the build.gradle file.